# Same font size on a website on different phones

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am currently developing a wordpress template and I've finally started to make it responsive, however font sizes are different on phones. For example, I own a Nokia Lumia with Microsoft Edge, and the text on my page is big. However, on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Chrome, the text is tiny. How can I make it so all the phones show a big text?

If needed, here's a link: http://acevix.com/development/temp/index.php/2015/12/12/hello-world/

Comment: Post a jsfiddle with your code, so we can see what is going on, i see you're using bootstrap, so try to specify your font size im em-s , because bootstrap sets base font for elements well on all platforms :)

Comment: I am mostly using em, as you can see on the link I'm only using px when I really need it. I didn't set a default size though (in pixels). Do I need to do that in order to fix this? If yes, how?

Comment: No you don't need to, bootstrap does all of the work, if you included it ;)

Comment: are you setting <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in the header ?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a wide range of display-sizes and resolutions it is mostly the best way to set the size of any object on a page by *relative units*, i.e. `em`, `vw` or `vh`.

see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths

*Absolute units* like `px` or `in` are dependent of the pixel-density of a device. So if you have a display with 250ppi and another with 150 ppi the text will be bigger in the latter case.

see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths

Comment: I am mostly using em, as you can see on the link I'm only using px when I really need it. I didn't set a default size though (in pixels). Do I need to do that in order to fix this? If yes, how?

Comment: em sets the size relative to the parent font-size. So if you define the font-size in a parent element with absolute units, then em will also be dependent on an absolute value... or in other words it will not be dependent of the display size. If I'm not wrong you set the font-size to 14px in the body-tag. This could be the cause.

Comment: @treeno if you have seen his page is using bootstrap, and bootstrap sets base fonts for elements, so only need is to define units in em's :)

Comment: is bootstrap doing this relative to the display-size?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using em-s , since you're using bootstrap, and one more thing that your site doesn't have, as i could see the code is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is really important tag for responsive design try adding it :)

Comment: could you explain why the meta-tag is important for responsive design?

Comment: why would i :) you need to instruct device to adopt site to it's width ,and it's highly recommended to put it,and here is more about it : http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972